# What is the best way to validate/debug Mathml with free online tools?

Tags: xml, editor, validation, mathml

i have some xml with math ml inside, and i would like to find some free tools preferably online which i can use to validate and if possible even edit math ml.

Anyone knows of any good tools which i can use to do this?
Thanks.

### Edit:

Does firefox 3.03 natively support MathML? I can't get some equations to show up at all. I know in [IE i use the MathPlayer](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathplayer/download.htm) to get it running.

Here is the code block, [fyi, i try just copy and pasting this as a htm and running it in IE7 which with the help of MathPlayer convert it nicely while in FF3 it looks gibberish]:

```
<HTML XMLNS:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<head>
</head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" onresize="javascript:hideNavigation()" onkeydown="onKeyDown()" style="background:#FFFFFF">
</b><font COLOR="#000000" FACE="Times New Roman" SIZE="3" >&#1581;&#1604;&#1604;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1576;&#1575;&#1585;&#1577;<font FACE="Times New Roman">&nbsp;<font FACE="Times New Roman">&#1578;&#1605;&#1575;&#1605;&#1575;&#1611;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#1573;&#1604;&#1609;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#1593;&#1608;&#1575;&#1605;&#1604;&#1607;&#1575;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#1575;&#1604;&#1571;&#1608;&#1604;&#1610;&#1577;<font FACE="Times New Roman">&nbsp;  </font> </font></font></font> 
<span style="font-family: Times new roman">
<object id="MathPlayer" classid="clsid:32F66A20-7614-11D4-BD11-00104BD3F987">
</object>
<?import namespace="m" implementation="#MathPlayer" ?>
<m:math xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><m:mn>3</m:mn>
<m:msup><m:mrow><m:mi>s</m:mi>
</m:mrow>
<m:mrow><m:mn>2</m:mn>
</m:mrow>
</m:msup>
<m:msup><m:mrow><m:mi>x</m:mi>
</m:mrow>
<m:mrow><m:mn>2</m:mn>
</m:mrow>
</m:msup>
<m:mo>&amp;plus;</m:mo>
<m:mn>42</m:mn>
<m:msup><m:mrow><m:mi>s</m:mi>
</m:mrow>
<m:mrow><m:mn>2</m:mn>
</m:mrow>
</m:msup>
<m:mi>hx</m:mi>
<m:mo>&amp;plus;</m:mo>
<m:mn>72</m:mn>
<m:msup><m:mrow><m:mi>s</m:mi>
</m:mrow>
<m:mrow><m:mn>2</m:mn>
</m:mrow>
</m:msup>
<m:msup><m:mrow><m:mi>h</m:mi>
</m:mrow>
<m:mrow><m:mn>2</m:mn>
</m:mrow>
</m:msup>
</m:math>&nbsp;</span>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Anyone know of any good tips to check on what could be the problem here? As of now i can only suspect the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
http://www.adrian.zentner.name/content/projects/xml/mathml/onlineEditor/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Mozilla MathML Tester](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/mathml/demo/tester.html) on their old website.

There is also a [Wolfram Research MathML redering tool](http://www.mathmlcentral.com/Tools/FromMathML.jsp).

One can also check the MathML code for errors at [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), with no rendering.